# How I can made a custom post type to page templates?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

In my site, I created a `custom post type` called: "Pictures"

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'Pictures',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Pictures' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Pictures' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
    )
  );
}
```

In my site, I want to have two pages: Index and Pictures

->Index: It had posts only of text
->Pictures: It had posts only of pictures

In Dashboard -> Posts. All posts that I did go straight to the index.

I wonder how I can access the Dashboard-> Pictures-> Add New
. And each post I do, fall into the "Pictures" page.

How I can do this?

Comment: you already have that with your post type archive, but note that the first argument of register post type must be `pictures`, no capital letters or spaces can be in the post type slug.

Comment: I use a plugin called custom post type UI to create cpt, honestly saves me a lot of time & effort https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add:

```
'supports'  =>  array('title', 'editor','page-attributes','thumbnail')
```

add this to your array after 'singular name' => 'pictures'.

The thumbnail adds the featured image option to your post type.

You can access the post type archive: yoursite/archive-pictures, this will use your themes archive.php file if it exists.

Or you can create a custom post type archive template with a custom loop: archive-pictures.php.

Or you can create a custom page template and apply it to a page.

Both the post-type archive and custom page template would contain similar code: a custom post type loop like this:

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'pictures', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_title();
  echo '<div class="entry-content">';
  the_content();
  the_post_thumbnail("medium");
  echo '</div>';
endwhile;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. With this code and some changes, I got what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Hello maybe this can help, i use this kind of query to retrieve cpt query and display contents:

```
   <?php // querying Database
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'Pictures', 'posts_per_page' => 6);
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    ?>
    <?php // creating the loog
     if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>

- output goes here, like the_content() or what you need -  

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );  ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

more... your CPT register name must be all lowercase, and at the end of your plugin file you have to add something like this to be able to query your cpt

```
// Querying custom post type
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_pictures_post_types_to_query' );

function add_pictures_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'pictures' ) );
    return $query;
}
```